# Log into Google Calendar on an automation testing framework

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, authentication, selenium-webdriver, browser

According to [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en-GB) Google does not support logging in with automation testing frameworks. I am trying to populate a calendar with game release data I scraped from [here](https://www.gamesradar.com/au/video-game-release-dates/) to make a public calendar I can share on reddit. I have scraped the data but now i can't even log into Google on the webdriver. What are the solutions to this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r")
pdb.set_trace()
#manual log in gives error
```

Error message: You are trying to sign in from a browser or app that doesn't allow us to keep your account secure.
Try using a different browser [Learn More](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some hack or workaround for this by setting the User-Agent in Chrome.

**To achieve this you need to use the chrome user-agent command line option.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=PUT_USER_AGENT_HERE")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.get("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r")
pdb.set_trace()
#manual log in gives error
```

**How to get the User-Agent:**

- Open your actual browser.
- Right-click and open inspect element.
- Now go to console.
- Now copy-paste below code.

**Code:**

```
navigator.userAgent
```

**Example:** *Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36*

Comment: I don't get it! You could just set the user agent . Why set this through the console?

Comment: You need to pass the user-agent to manipulate the google and avoid it to detect your agent. Just forget the console part, it was just an example.

Comment: Just use the above code with opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36")

Comment: Yep tried it ... Sometimes it works , Sometimes it doesn't .